# How to get SharePoint 2010 controls in toolbox

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

My application uses Visual Studio 2010 to develop an application in SharePoint 2010. I created a visual webpart and added a `<SharePoint:SPCalendarView ID="EventsCalendar1" width="100%" runat="server"></SharePoint:SPCalendarView>` I also found that there are many other controls which appears in intellisense. How can I add these controls to the toolbox? Is there any documentation available on how to use these controls?

Answer (score 1):

1. In Visual Studio on the Tools menu, click Choose Toolbox Items.
2. Click Browse.
3. The Open dialog box appears.
4. In the My Places Bar, select My Computer to browse for items
   installed on your computer drives. —or— In Look in, select My Network Places to browse for items located on a network share.
5. Click OK.

[image]

Reference:

- [How to: Add Items to the Toolbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165355%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [MSDN Social SPCalendarView](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/ea37b8f2-cae9-4850-a6c2-47f6c1768148)

Comment: I was specifically asking for SharePoint controls like SPCalendarView, SPGridView etc

Comment: Inside the .NET Freamework Componets are SharePoint controls as well. The procedure to add is the same too. Are you getting reference issues while opening the control?